# javascript in twig template layout yields error

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, templates, twig

i have a base twig template where i can insert body and js according to my need.Base template is like following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {{ block("stylesheets") }}
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div align="center">

        {{ block("body") }}

    </div>
</div>
{{ block("javascripts") }}

</body>
</html>
```

And i have a welcome.html which will use this template.Welcome page has some html and javascript.It renders the html inside it if no js is provided.If i provide any javascript it stops working and i get the following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'A
>   block must start with a tag name.' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\PHPMVC\Elixir\View\Welcome\welcome.html:14
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\PHPMVC\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\TokenParser\Block.php(40):
>   Twig_Parser->subparse(Array, true) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\PHPMVC\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Parser.php(190):
>   Twig_TokenParser_Block->parse(Object(Twig_Token)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\PHPMVC\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Parser.php(103):
>   Twig_Parser->subparse(NULL, false) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\PHPMVC\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php(692):
>   Twig_Parser->parse(Object(Twig_TokenStream)) #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\PHPMVC\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php(750):
>   Twig_Environment->parse(Object(Twig_TokenStream)) #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\PHPMVC\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php(447):
>   Twig_Environment->compileSource(Object(Twig_Source)) #6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\PHPMVC\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php(362):
>   Twig_E in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\PHPMVC\Elixir\View\Welcome\welcome.html on
>   line 14

Welcome.html :

```
{ extends "Base/Base.html" }
{ block body }
<ul>
{ for user in users }
    <li>{{ user.name}} is {{ user.age }} years old !</li>
{ endfor }
</ul>
<input type = 'button' value = 'mybtn' id = 'btn'>

{ endblock body }

{ block javascripts }
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){

 })

</script>
{ endblock javascripts }
```

i have used lexer to rewrite syntax rule like following :

```
$lexer = new \Twig_Lexer($twig,array(
                         'tag_block'    =>array('{','}'),
                         'tag_variable' =>array('{{','}}')
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your lexxer rewrite will match your js as twig tag block

the brackets of that js object:

```
function(){}
```

you could make use of the varbatim tag

```
{ block javascripts }
{ verbatim }
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){

 })

</script>
{ endverbatim }
{ endblock javascripts }
```

the content between `verbatim` will not be parsed by twig

https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/verbatim.html